# Why is it necessary to have default constructor in this when i already have one constructor

Tags: c++

Why is it necessary to have a default constructor in this case I mean if in class car if I add car(){}function then no error is being shown!! but I already have one constructor car(int p,string s)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class car{
    int price;
    int model_no;
    string name;
    public:
    void print(){
        cout<<name<<endl;cout<<price<<endl;
    }
    car(int p,string s){
        price=p;
        name=s;
    }
    car(car&x){
        price=x.price;
    }

};
int main(){
    car a;
    a(5,"BMW");
    a.print();
    //cout<<a.name;
    //cout<<sizeof(car);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `car a;` invokes default constructor, `a(5,"BMW");` invokes non-existing `operator ()`

Comment: A user-provided constructor suppresses the compiler-generated default constructor. And good! If you have gone to the effort of telling the compiler what it should do with members, and which members must be passed to a constructor, why would you want to let it continue assuming that it's fine to create an instance with uninitialised members? Oh, and there's a point: Your `model_no` is uninitialised. That's UB waiting to happen. You should write basic-typed members ike `int_price{}; int model_no{}` to ensure that never bites you. Edit: After realising the main problem, I VTC as a typo.

Answer (score 4):

```
car a;
```

tries to  call the standard constructor, because you give no parameters. But there is no standard constructor, so it's requesting one.

```
a(5, "BMW");
```

tries to call an operator `()` but there is no operator like this.

Simply write `car a(5, "BMW");` instead of `car a; a(5, "BMW")`